# add hyperlink to excel sheet created by pandas dataframe to_excel method

Tags: python, excel, pandas, hyperlink

I have converted a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) DataFrame to an Excel sheet using [`df.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

Now, I want to add hyperlinks to the values in one column. In other words, when a customer sees my excel sheet, he would be able to click on a cell and bring up a webpage (depending on the value in this cell).

Answer (score 32):

Building on the approach by @guillaume-jacquenot we can use `apply` to apply this to an entire Series.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2000, 2001, 2002 , 2003]})
```

For cleanliness, I wrote a helper method.

```
def make_hyperlink(value):
    url = "https://custom.url/{}"
    return '=HYPERLINK("%s", "%s")' % (url.format(value), value)
```

Then, `apply` it to the Series:

```
df['hyperlink'] = df['Year'].apply(make_hyperlink)
```

> 

```
    Year    hyperlink
0   2000    =HYPERLINK("https://custom.url/2000", "2000")
1   2001    =HYPERLINK("https://custom.url/2001", "2001")
2   2002    =HYPERLINK("https://custom.url/2002", "2002")
3   2003    =HYPERLINK("https://custom.url/2003", "2003")
```

Comment: As an improvement, you could just pass `make_hyperlink` function directly into `.apply` method like `df['Year'].apply(make_hyperlink)`.

Answer (score 25):

You could use the `HYPERLINK` function

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'link':['=HYPERLINK("http://www.someurl.com", "some website")']})
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the hyperlink when reading the file into a Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Could you a give an example where you add a hyperlink to a specific cell? Also, have you succeed in passing anchor in the URL? It does not seem possible from what I have seen

Comment: just run `df.to_excel('test.xlsx')` on the above code and try it out, i just tried an anchor link and it worked for me

Comment: How can I write a link containing `"` in it? Thanks

Comment: Found the answer so I write it here in case it will help other people. To write a url with a `"` in it you need to replace the `"` with `%7B`. One can use `str.replace()` for that.

Answer (score 2):

From @maxymoo's answer, here is a full example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2000, 2001, 2002 , 2003]})
df['link'] = '-'
df.set_value(0, 'link', '=HYPERLINK("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000", 2000)')
df.set_value(1, 'link', '=HYPERLINK("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001", 2001)')
df.set_value(2, 'link', '=HYPERLINK("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002", 2002)')
df.set_value(3, 'link', '=HYPERLINK("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2003", 2003)')
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(5)), columns=['a'])

df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: '<a href="http://youtube.com/{0}">link</a>'.format(x))

HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

Comment: This doesn't create a hyperlink in the dataframe; it creates an HTML version of the dataframe. The other answers that use `to_excel` have the right approach.

Comment: you also need `from IPython.display import HTML`

Answer (score 1):

I was generating text files from a excel file and wanted to link the names of the generated .txt files to a particular existing column in the Dataframe.

I was trying to push the local drive directory where the generated .txt files are stored, to the corresponding "File Name". So that on clicking the file name, it will open the .txt file.

[image: The dataframe]

```
rancheck_DF = pd.read_excel(excel_file, delim_whitespace = True, encoding = 'utf-8')

for index_df in range(len(rancheck_DF)):

    Desc = rancheck_DF.loc[index_df,'Description Text']

    MainFile = rancheck_DF.loc[index_df,'File Name']

    fileName = r'.\Documents\TestF\TestF_{}.txt'.format(index_df)

    with open(fileName, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as txtfile:
        txtfile.write(Desc)

    rancheck_DF.loc[index_df,'File Name'] = '=HYPERLINK("{}","{}")'.format(fileName,MainFile)

rancheck_DF.to_excel('./damn.xlsx', index=None)
```