# how do I make one column of excel hyperlink (to another column which has the link) using pandas?

Tags: excel, pandas

I have started with pyhton and pandas today only and I am a noob coder, so please explain in detail.
I have got this kind of code from
[add hyperlink to excel sheet created by pandas dataframe to_excel method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820069/add-hyperlink-to-excel-sheet-created-by-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-method)

df = pd.DataFrame({'link':['=HYPERLINK("http://www.someurl.com", "some website")']})

but I dont understand to which column is it adding the link to and I have to add such that I mention ony column and It should take the value of link itself from that column.

Comment: I think first check http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html and then this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31821781/2901002).

Answer (score 0):

I am able to figure this out myself, took quite a long time though

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

workbook1 = load_workbook('pandas.xlsx')

worksheet1 = workbook1.active
column_indices = [12] #my hyperlinks are in 12th column

for row in range(1,worksheet.nrows):

```
for col in column_indices:
    filelocation = worksheet.cell_value(row, col)
    text = worksheet.cell_value(row, col+2)
    worksheet1.cell(row=row+1, column=col-3).value = '=HYPERLINK("'+filelocation+'","'+text+'")'
```

workbook1.save('pandas_simple.xlsx')