# How to add hyperlinks for value in column using Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, url, hyperlink

I got 3 columns in my dataframe.

Example:

```
name = ['iphone']
price = ['1000']
url = ['https://iphone.com/']
MY_DF = pd.DataFrame({'name': name, 'price':price})
MY_DF.to_excel('123.xlsx')
```

I need did it in **loop** in my dataframe.

How to apply url as hyperlink to price? and export it to xlsx
result need to be like:

[image]

The methods described in this article: [add hyperlink to excel sheet created by pandas dataframe to_excel method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820069/add-hyperlink-to-excel-sheet-created-by-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-method) do not suit me.

In my situation every url is unique and I don't know how to right apply them for my 'price'.

Seems like this could work, but I don't know how to loop it:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add hyperlink to excel sheet created by pandas dataframe to\_excel method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820069/add-hyperlink-to-excel-sheet-created-by-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-method)

Comment: @HarryPlotter
I don't think so

Comment: Please update your post with a sample of the DataFrame. It's not clear from the example how it's formated. Do you have 3 separate columns: product name, price   and url?

Comment: @HarryPlotter i was find solution, see below. anyway thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

```
def make_hyperlink(value):
    url = "{}"
    return '=HYPERLINK("%s", "%s")' % (url.format(value).split(' ')[0], url.format(value).split(' ')[1])
```

Il combine my url and price as `prices = 'urls' +' '+'price'` append it to main dataframe as ['price']
and apply next    `myDF['price'] = myDF['price'].apply(lambda x: make_hyperlink(x))`
and it works! =)